# The C++ Programming Language 12.7 question 2

Tags: c++, console-application, character

I am doing an exercise from The C++ Programming language (page 325, exercise 12.7, question 2).

It says:

> Implement a simple graphics system using whatever graphics facilities
>   are available on your system (if you dont have a good graphics system
>   or have no experience with one, you might consider a simple "Huge bit
>   ASCII implementation" where a point is a character position and you
>   write by placing a suitable container, such as * in a position)

Now, what I gather from that, is that if I dont want to use GDI+ or Direct X then I can do this in a console app using chars like `_`,`*`, or `-`.

Am I thinking about this the right way?

If I am, am I right in thinking that I need to be able to draw a character anywhere on the console?

If so, how do I draw a `char` anywhere on the console?

Or I could be wrong and you can tell he what I might want to try (not GDI+ / DirectX if possible)

Comment: Have you considered using spaces to space out the asterisks (*) or underline characters (_)?

Comment: @0A0D I gather you mean like . . . if I pass ('*', 8, 10) into a drawing function then a loop will add 10 return carrages and then 8 spaces? What if i then use this function again? Can you see the problem?

Comment: Whatever you need to do, just space it out as needed. Use for loops, etc. That's what it is trying to teach you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to draw a character anywhere to the console you really need to use an operating system specific library for console access, or a cross-platform console library.

If you were doing this for Windows you would use the [Windows Console API (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087.aspx), a function that could draw a character to a specific location is [FillConsoleOutputCharacter (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682663.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that ANSI escape sequences could be used, but having read your question and investigated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), it seems these no longer exist.

The best option appears to be to use the windows console APIs, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682010%28VS.85%29.aspx).

There looks to be a pretty good example of how you might proceed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685032%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Good luck with this, it sounds interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Fond memories of doing this in computer class, back when we had chaarcter sets with ▄ ▀ █. Double-resolution graphics ;). If you wanted one in column 8, you'd print 7 spaces in front of it. And if you wanted it at line 3, you'd print two `\n` in front. But yes, you'd have to consider up front what you were going to draw. To redraw one character, you'd have to redraw everything.